# nav pagination not show

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a problem , my code is make pagination `post_meta` , its work , but link to paginate still use `https://yourweb.com/post-title/2` not use paginate link `https://yourweb.com/post-title/page/2` , and if i type this link `https://yourweb.com/post-title/page/2` this will return to `https://yourweb.com/post-title/` , and nav pagination not show 
this my code

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint( get_query_var('paged')) : 1 ;
    $ids = get_the_ID();
    $args = array('paged' => $paged ,  'post__in' => array($ids));
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
 while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
     $metas = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'value_gallery',false);
            foreach ($metas as $meta) {
                $key_val = explode(",", $meta);
                $image_chunk = array_chunk($key_val, 3);

                $page = get_query_var('page');
                $page = $page > 1 ? $page - 1 : 0 ;
                if (isset($key_val[$page])) {
                    foreach ($image_chunk[$page] as $image) {
                        echo "<div class='col-lg-4'>".
                        wp_get_attachment_image($image,"cherry-thumb-a") ."</div>";
                    }
                }
            }
endwhile;
the_posts_pagination( array(
'mid_size'  => 2,
'prev_text' => __( '<', 'textdomain' ),
'next_text' => __( '>', 'textdomain' ),
 ) );
wp_reset_postdata();
 endif;
```

i will happy if anyone can help me :) ,many thanks for attention